# angular 6 FormGroup/FormControl iterator issue

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have a fromGroup and 7 FormControl inside (name, address, zipcode, etc)
     When the page is initialized, only the first FormControl is enabled, and the others are disabled. Only after the user enter his name, the others FormControls are supposed to be enabled. I would like to iterate over all the formcontrols and enable each one inside the loop, without having typing all the formcontrols.
I would like to do something like that :

```
for (const field in this.form.controls) { 
   this.form.get(field).enable();
}
```

or like that :

```
Object.keys( this.form.controls).forEach(key => {
   this.form.controls[key].enable();
});
```

But unfortunately the other formcontrols are never enabled

Any idea why ?

thanks
youss

Comment: Have you disabled them during initialize? Is it working? And how are you calling a method to enable them back? Provide more details to help you serve better.

Comment: Yes the other formcontrols are disabled during init and this part works.
When editing the name formcontrol, there is a subscriber which listen to the name formcontrol:
`code`
this.insuredAddressForm.get('name').valueChanges
      .subscribe(inserted => {
        if(inserted.length > 0){
              // here i want to enable all the formcontrols
           }
        }
`code`

Comment: I do not see any issue with your code. Can you reproduce the issue in https://stackblitz.com

Comment: Only issue that I see is, you have subscribed to `insuredAddressForm` form control, and you are trying to modify `form` named form controls `this.form.controls[key].enable();`

Comment: You could have framed your question better explaining your error. Else it will lead to unnecessary workaround like this. Anyways, I have made an answer to provide a solution for your error mentioned in the comments below on the other answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should exclude modifying `name` form control inside its own value changes `subscription`. Because this will make a recursive call and give the

> maximum call stack size exceeded

error. And also you should not be enabling `name` control again, because it is already `enabled`.

```
this.form.get('name').valueChanges.subscribe(inserted => {
      if (inserted.length > 0) { 
        Object.keys(this.form.controls)
        .forEach(key => {
          if(key !== 'name')
          this.form.controls[key].enable()
        });
      }
 });
```

Comment: damn man you are right :) it was actually my problem .
One last question why do we put Object.keys ? 
I understand that we need to iterate over each formControl with the formControlName as key , but why Object ?
thanks Amit

Comment: `Object.keys` will give you the keys of any object. In your case, `names` of each form control, (keys of `this.form.controls`). Here  `this.form.controls` is an object so.

Comment: Done :)
Best regards Amit

Answer (score 1):

This sample works for me: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7xo9yd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

You should post more code details for us in order to encounter your problem.

Comment: it actually worked with:

  Object.keys(this.form.controls)
        .forEach(key => {
          this.form.controls[key].enable()
        });

But as iam using :

this.insuredAddressForm.get('name').valueChanges .subscribe(inserted =>.....

it's like each character typed in the first input is a subscriber and i get :

ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: Iam using a subscriber because i want to keep the logic inside the component.ts file and not put a method call inside the input itself like in your example